# I want to split a string into two parts, before number and after number

Tags: php, regex

```
$string1 = "Clindamycin 1.2%";
$string2 = "Ranitidine HCl 150 mg";
$string3 = "Amlodipine 5.5 mg & 10 mg.";
preg_split('/[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]/', $string3);
```

I have tried with the preg_split method it returns the characters before and after the number. but I need the number also. And it does not work with $string3 perfectly. I want something like this.

```
$drug = "Amlodipine"; 
$weight = "5.5 mg & 10 mg."; 
$drug = "Clindamycin";
$weight = "1.2%";
```

*Note these strings will come from the database so it can be any of these 3 strings type.*

Comment: Are there `drug` names with a number in them ?

Comment: In `$string2`, I assume you need the result to be:`$drug = Ranitidine HCl` and `$weight = 150 mg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function splitDrug($drug){
    if ( preg_match('/(.*?)(\d.*)/', $drug, $matches) ) {
        $response['drug'] = trim($matches[1]);
        $response['weight'] = trim($matches[2]);
        return $response;
    } return false;
}

$string1 = splitDrug("Clindamycin 1.2%");
$string2 = splitDrug("Ranitidine HCl 150 mg");
$string3 = splitDrug("Amlodipine 5.5 mg & 10 mg.");

echo('Drug: '.$string1['drug'].' Weight: '.$string1['weight']);
echo('Drug: '.$string2['drug'].' Weight: '.$string2['weight']);
echo('Drug: '.$string3['drug'].' Weight: '.$string3['weight']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), you can make the pattern a bit more specific as your current pattern will split on a numeric value, and use a capture group to keep the delimiter after using split.

```
\h*([+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:%|\h+mg\b).*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\h*` Match optinal horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1** (to keep using preg_split)

  - `[+-]?\d*\.?\d+` Match optional `-` or `+` and digits with an optional decimal part
  - `(?:%|\h+mg\b)` Match either `%` or `mg` (Extend the alternatives to make it more specific)
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9OnSJ9/1) and a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/QAQC4).

```
$strings = ["Clindamycin 1.2%", "Ranitidine HCl 150 mg","Amlodipine 5.5 mg & 10 mg."];

foreach($strings as $s) {
    $parts = preg_split("/\h*([+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:%|\h+mg\b).*)/", $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($parts);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Clindamycin
    [1] => 1.2%
)
Array
(
    [0] => Ranitidine HCl
    [1] => 150 mg
)
Array
(
    [0] => Amlodipine
    [1] => 5.5 mg & 10 mg.
)
```